# Cannot see page content?

Tags: 7

I'm building a custom theme for Drupal 7.xx, which is part of my internship.
I've been developing this theme for quite a while now, but I still consider myself an absolute beginner when it comes to theming for Drupal.

During the process, I've ran into quite a few problems which (luckily) I've been able to solve with the help of google (including Drupal Answers) so first of all thanks for that!

One of the problems I seem to be unable to solve, is that I cannot see the page content anywhere. So far I've added all content of the pages in blocks, which I've assigned to be rendered out by a region called 'cont_page_block', and which I have declared in my .info document.

To clarify: When I add a new page, I fill in the page title and body, but it doesn't appear on the page. Also, when I add a news article, I can see the teaser on my 'news summary' but when I try to click on it (which works though) it redirects me to a new page (URL states ?q=node/xx) which is, ofcourse, empty.

Here's the code I use in my page.tpl.php file to render the region:

```
   <div class="cont_page_block">    <?php print render($page['cont_page_block']); ?>
                                    <?php print render($content); ?>               </div>
```

And here's the declaration of my regions in my .info file:

```
regions[cont_page_block] = content-page-block  
regions[content] = content
```

Am I missing a line of PHP code in my page.tpl.php file?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

```
<?php print render($page['content']); ?>
```

Edit:
To further the above, if you want to see the action links/titles/tabs you can print those by:

```
<?php if ($title): ?>
      <h1 class="title" id="page-title"> <?php print $title; ?> </h1>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php if ($tabs): ?>
      <div class="tabs"> <?php print render($tabs); ?> </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
      <?php if ($action_links): ?>
      <ul class="action-links">
        <?php print render($action_links); ?>
      </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
      <?php /*?><?php print $feed_icons; ?><?php */?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

I've copied your code and I am now able to print out the page title, yet the remaining content still isn't visible.


 note: I've used the <?php print render($page['content']); ?>

Comment: To illustrate my problem, here's a snapshot of the page:    http://i.imgur.com/TQFfgvL.jpg   The content should be visible in the orange box in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Somebody slap me please.

I was about to take a smoke break to empty my head about the issue, and I suddenly realized I forgot to add the 'Site-Content' to the deisgnated region in the 'Block Management' area.

Problem solved!

Now please excuse me while I quietly sit ashamed in a corner.